# show in flutter a list view of documents in the realtime database whose name is in a list in the firestore database

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a flutter application in visual code, and I really need to be able to use both databases of Firebase simultaneously. I can't show the documents in the realtime database whose names are in a list in the firestore database.
I have the "Users" collection, where each document has some of the users characteristics. Within a user document we have, for example, their name, email address, etc. There is then a list called "smartScales" where the code names of the user's products are (strings). In the realtime database I have all the product code names in the "SmartScales" path, and within each one we have things like name, size, weight, etc. What I'd like to do is display in listView format the products from the realtime database that the current user has in their "smartScales" list, and not all of them.

[This image shows the "email" field and the "smartScales" list of a user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NciVs.png)

[This image shows the path "SmartScales" with the product's code name and then its characteristics, the most important of which is its name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDJta.png)

Is this possible? If so, can anyone help me? I'd like to thank anyone who tries to help me :)

I've tried various things, but I always get code errors or it simply doesn't work. The furthest I've gotten with my attempts is to simply print the "smartScales" list that the current user has, and another was to show the data I have in the realtime database, but all of them. I can't seem to put the two together :(

[initial code with imports, variables etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyiio.png)

[printing the "smartScales" list that the current user has](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqpqt.png)

[data that i have in realtime database, is not in listview, even though I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3ftw.png)